# Closure which captures outer scope as field of struct in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, parser-combinators

I am new to Rust and I am trying to create combinator parser in it. Here is the code:

```
enum Parser<T: Copy + Eq> {
    Ok,
    Eof,
    Satisfy { predicate:  Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> bool> },
    Element { elem : T }
}

impl<T: Copy + Eq> Parser<T> {
    fn parse<'a, P>(&self, input: &'a [T]) -> Option<(&'a [T], P)>
    where
        P: Default,
        T: Into<P>
    {
        match self {
            Parser::Ok => Some((input, P::default())),
            Parser::Eof => match input {
                [] => None,
                _ => Some((input, P::default())),
            },
            Parser::Satisfy { predicate } => match input {
                [] => None,
                [x, rest @ ..] => {
                    if predicate(x) {
                        Some((rest, T::into(*x)))
                    } else {
                        None
                    }
                }
            },
            Parser::Element { elem } => {
                let to_match = *elem;
                Parser::Satisfy { predicate: Box::new(move|x| *x == to_match) }.parse(input)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parser::Ok, Parser::Eof and Parser::Satisfy are working fine but I struggled with realization of Parser::Element (which must much only exact element). I want to realize method parse for it with creation of Parser::Satisfy with predicate of eq between argument **x** and given **elem**. But I run into this error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:32:46
   |
32 |                 Parser::Satisfy { predicate: Box::new(move|x| *x == to_match) }.parse(input)
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
8  | impl<T: Copy + Eq + 'static> Parser<T> {
   |                   +++++++++
```

I feel there is some problem with lifetimes but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: In the next time, please paste the full error from `cargo check` (not your IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dyn Trait` contains things. These things may have lifetimes. Therefore, `dyn Trait` also has a lifetime.

This lifetime, like functions' lifetimes, can be elided. [The full rules are somewhat complicated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes), but when in an ADT, the lifetime is assumed to be `'static`. You can specify another lifetime with `dyn Trait + 'lifetime`.

Thus, the `Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> bool>` in your enum is actually `Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> bool + 'static>`.

But the problem is that the function you assign into it captures `to_match`, of type `T`. And type `T` may contain a non-`'static` lifetime. For example, it may contain `&'non_static str`. This is the error.

This has two possible solutions.

Either accept that and require `T` to be `'static`:

```rust
impl<T: Copy + Eq + 'static> Parser<T> {
```

Or allow non-`'static` lifetime for the function:

```rust
enum Parser<'a, T: Copy + Eq> {
    Ok,
    Eof,
    Satisfy { predicate:  Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> bool + 'a> },
    Element { elem : T }
}

impl<T: Copy + Eq> Parser<'_, T> {
```

Comment: **enum Parser<'a, T: Copy + Eq> {
    Ok,
    Eof,
    Satisfy { predicate:  Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> bool + 'a> },
    Element { elem : T }
}**

In this solution does **'a** means that environmental variables in predicate must live as much as my parser? Am I correct?

Comment: @anon1453092865 `'a` is just a lifetime. It means the function's captured data must live as long as this lifetime.